# Is there a non hacky way to move the "Legal" Label in MKMapView to the top left corner?

Tags: swift, xcode, mkmapview

I was using layout margins and adjusting coordinate space to do this, but found that it would constantly break my constraints. Is there a legitimate way of handling this, or do I have to work around the legal label?

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but I'm pretty sure that can't be customized.